# Asynchronous wait failed for XCUI tests:Exceeded timeout of 60 seconds, with unfulfilled expectations

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, fastlane, xcuitest

```
 let button = app.buttons["BACK TO DASHBOARD"]
    let exists = NSPredicate(format: "exists == 1")
    expectation(for: exists, evaluatedWith: button) {
        //             If the button exists, also check that it is enabled
        if button.isEnabled {
            button.tap()
            return true
        } else {
            // Do not fulfill the expectation since the button is not enabled
            return false
        }
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 60, handler: nil)
```

> I can able to run through in Xcode, The tests successfully run in Xcode, But during fastlane scan, I got error: Asynchronous wait failed, Exceeded time limit.How can I fix this?
>
> I have a button in disabled state, After certain time, the button gets enabled, Now I can click the enabled button. It runs correctly in Xcode, But It fails in Fastlane scan.